# Sequelise Transactions on multiple databases - MySQL

Tags: sequelize.js

At our shop, we are running Two databases Member and Address. We want to commit member table only if address table is updated properly else rollback member. We are using sequelise transactions but the issue here is one transaction is pointing to Member table and other with Address table. Is there any solution to achieve transactions across multiple tables.

Comment: Do you have 2 databases or 2 tables in 1 database? Also provide code that you have got so far.

Comment: I have two databases - Member and Contact databases containing Member and Address tables respectively.

Comment: Add your code here

Comment: I have the same problem to solve, looks like there isn't any suck feature in sequelize. I am looking to implement a rollback of my own.